# Web Application using OSGi and GWT

Tags: web-applications, gwt, osgi

Which is a good architecture for a Web Application using OSGI and GWT as UI?

The aim is to use bundles to make bundles of web interface sections. If I add new bundle it will add new features (a menu for example) on the user interface, which cooperate with existing ones.

Comment: That's an interesting idea.  I'd want to see if this could be done since you have to run the GWT compiler to get it into the JS/HTML format.  Would you have to run the compiler each time a module is added/removed?

Comment: I wouldn't run the compiler each time you add a module.

Comment: Then how would you serve up the pages?  I was under the impression that you needed to run the compiler to get it to spit out the HTML/JS so anytime your code base changes, you'd run it again.

Comment: I do not have a single GWT module, but many modules that interact.
Imagine having a basic application with menus. The default implementation does nothing.
If I install a new bundle that includes a GWT module with a new feature of the application (eg customer management) this module will be made visible automatically in the menu and clicking on the corresponding menu item will open a window with interfaces defined in the bundle.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please see a similar discussion on the GWT mailing list - http://groups.google.com/group/google-web-toolkit/msg/4a3f912cb89a7256

To summarize - 
GWT's architecture is orthogonal to your requirement of multiple modules loaded at runtime. There are ways to achieve dynamic modules in GWT, but it is never going to be optimal.

In general, you would define a javascript interface for each of your modules, and then export those methods from GWT using [GWT Exporter](http://code.google.com/p/gwt-exporter/). Then you'd compile each of your modules independently. The modules will then interact at runtime using the javascript methods that you exported.

The price you pay is performance. Each module will duplicate common framework code (GWT + your own framework code), and there is nothing you can do to avoid it.