# GWT Dynamic Module Loading

Tags: gwt, dynamic, plugins

Is there a mechanism to dynamically load a GWT Module?

The idea is to create a pluggable GWT-based system: a core GWT module that dynamically loads another GWT module and a bus communication system to permit the communication through loaded modules.

Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Possible duplicate of [Web Application using OSGi and GWT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2567112/web-application-using-osgi-and-gwt/2567733#2567733)

Also, see the information in this GWT User forum thread - http://groups.google.com/group/google-web-toolkit/msg/4a3f912cb89a7256

To summarize, its possible, but not recommended. Your requirement is orthogonal to GWT's philosophy and architecture. If you must, the [GWT Exporter project](http://code.google.com/p/gwt-exporter/) is a useful starting point to enable communication between modules.

Comment: How can i reach the solution using GWT Exporter Project? 
Can i load dinamically a panel from another GWT Module?

Answer (score 1):

Code splitting does successfully handle the separated-loading issue -- but it does not address the separated-compilation issue.

Modular-interoperability with separated-compilation will never be the recommended default but GWT team should look into this in future.

If we are talking about a plug-in based architecture, different plug-in developer should develop their own UI and compile and give to the framework. Framework should dynamically load them.

I am still looking for and way to do it (do it better way).

Answer (score 0):

You can use code splitting to dynamically loading the code when ever you want.

Have a look
http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideCodeSplitting.html

Comment: The split code refer to same GWT module. I've modules developed by 3rd party that i want integrate in my existent modules.

Answer (score 0):

See also comments at http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/wiki/CodeSplitting, starting at 6th comment.