# MVC web container for OSGI?

Tags: java, model-view-controller, osgi

As I have no knowledge of servlets+jsp's, is there a web-container that does not deal with servlets for OSGI?

Preferably for an MVC web framework of some sort. For example microsoft has ASP.NET-MVC, which is pretty nice - is there something similar in java (and can I run it within osgi)?

Comment: Since when are servlets not compatible with the MVC pattern?  ASP.net MVC is *very* specific interpretation of the MVC pattern, and arguably not a very good one.

Comment: Is there an mvc servlet web framework then, that is compatible with OSGI?

Comment: Try Spring Dynamic Module and Spring MVC from Spring framework http://www.springsource.org/ Spring comes with all possible feature you can thing of, e.g. security, dependency injection, aop, osgi, web flow, web, mvc, etc.

Comment: Spring seems like a very big thing... I tried downloading it once, and it installed it's own version of Eclipse. Is there something leaner?

Comment: If what you download included Eclipse, then it was most likely the Spring IDE tooling which is built on top of Eclipse.  The "full" download of SpringFramework is still quite large (especially if you get all the deps) but its not quite as big.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at [vaadin](http://vaadin.com/home) which has an add-on [vaadin-osgi](http://vaadin.com/directory#addon/vaadin-osgi).  Vaadin is distributed as an osgi bundle out the gate, what vaadin-osgi gives you is a way to register your application as a servlet service through osgi DS along with some other niceties.  With the vaadin-osgi add-on you do not need an servlet container as it will just use the servlet services with your osgi container.  This way you will not need to learn a single thing about servlets as it will all happen behind the scenes.

Comment: Yes, all you need to do is expose a subclass of com.vaadin.Application as a service.  iPOJO, DS, Blueprint, or any other way of declaring OSGi services will work.

Comment: How is vaadin better than GWT? I mean if I can run vaadin in osgi - couldn't I run GWT in OSGI with the same ease? Or does vaadin add something to make it osgi-compliant?

Comment: See http://groups.google.com/group/google-web-toolkit/msg/4a3f912cb89a7256 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2567112/web-application-using-osgi-and-gwt for discussions on the issues of combining GWT with OSGi.  The basic gist is that gwt does a lot of compile time tricks to drive performance whereas vaadin defers much more to runtime.  You will be able to use more of the power of OSGi with a runtime framework such as Vaadin.  If you are willing to work with the trade offs then you can definitely use GWT.